# Difference between RSA.Encrypt() and RSA.EncryptValue()

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, rsa

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-3.1

I am watching the documentation of RSA and I can't understand the difference between `.Encrypt()` and `.EncryptValue()`. I can see that `.Encrypt()` uses a specified padding mode, but does it use the private key? For `.EncryptValue()` it says it uses the public key for encryption.

I want to have a function that ***encrypts with the private key*** and another that ***decrypts with the public key***.

Comment: i get your confusion, seems like the abstraction expects you to first exchange public keys, with which you then can use to encrypt data. yet RSA should theoretically be able to do it the otherway around too like you want to, but it doesn't seem to be supported

Comment: @MichaelRandall the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-3.1) explicitly discourage that: Developers are encouraged to program against the RSA base class rather than any specific derived class. The derived classes are intended for interop with the underlying system cryptographic libraries.

Comment: @PatrickBeynio thanks for explaining that, always good to learn something

Comment: *...that encrypts with the private key...* That is called signing, look to the signature classes to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've researched a bit more and it turns out that the method call (`RSA.EncryptValue()`) is not supported and a `NotSupportedException` is thrown out.

Additionally, `RSA.Decrypt()` uses the private key for decryption, but the `RSA.Encrypt()` uses the public ***and private key*** for encryption, I am not sure why tho. I will post a different question for that.

Finally, the library, as far as I saw (maybe I am wrong here, correct me in this case), does support signing (encryption with private key) and verifying (decryption with private key), but it only returns a bool if the verification is correct or not. There is no method that decrypts with public key and gives back data.